# Command '['git' 'clone', '--recurse-submodules', '--', 'ssh://git@git/b2b/py_client.git'] returned non-zero exit status 128

Tags: python, git, python-poetry, code128

I am trying to create virtualenv with `make setup` and poetry in Git Bash:

```
$ make setup
poetry install --no-root
Creating virtualenv ad-ml in C:\Users\user1\Documents\ad_ml\.venv
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe'
, 'clone', '--recurse-submodules', '--', 'ssh://git@git.bcb.local:7999/b2b/py_client.git', 
'C:\\Users\\EMANZH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pypoetry-git-py_clien9fdvh9lr']'
 returned non-zero exit status 128.

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\_compat.py:217 in run
```

and get CalledProcessError with exit status 128 and another exception:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\__init__.py", line 5, in main
    return Application().run()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\console_application.py", line 142, in run
    trace.render(io, simple=isinstance(e, CliKitException))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 232, in render
    return self._render_exception(io, self._exception)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 269, in _render_exception
    self._render_snippet(io, current_frame)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 289, in _render_snippet
    self._render_line(io, code_line)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 402, in _render_line
    io.write_line("{}{}".format(indent * " ", line))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\cleo\io\io_mixin.py", line 65, in write_line
    super(IOMixin, self).write_line(string, flags)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\io.py", line 66, in write_line
    self._output.write_line(string, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 69, in write_line
    self.write(string, flags=flags, new_line=True)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 61, in write
    self._stream.write(to_str(formatted))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\io\output_stream\stream_output_stream.py", line 24, in write
    self._stream.write(string)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>
```

Are there any ideas how to fix this error, any help would be much appreciated.

pc windows 10, git bash 2.34.0, cloned repo with sourcetree from bitbucket, python 3.8.8

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is similar to [`python-poetry/poetry` issue 3297](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3297), which refers to a [`pypa/virtualenv` issue 1986](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1986)

The first link includes (by [Daniel Taylor](https://github.com/Skyscimitar)):

> We downgrade virtualenv inside the conda environment in our circle CI windows executors, not sure if it with `pip` or not.
>
> So adding a step like this to your `yml` config should fix the issue (or just adding `virtualenv=20.0.33` to the step where you install your `conda` dependencies):
>
> ```
> - run: conda install virtualenv=20.0.33
> ```

---

The [OP Taky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17450428/taky) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70025914/command-git-clone-recurse-submodules-ssh-gitgit-b2b-py-cli/70031570#comment123820737_70031570):

> I changed `dependency` link to `py_client.git` in `pyproject.toml` from "`ssh`" to "`https`", and that's worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I changed dependency link to py_client.git in pyproject.toml from "ssh" to "https" and that's worked for me.

Comment: @Taky Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.